# AttributeError when trying to getTileImageByGid in pyTMX

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pytmx

I am trying to load a TMX map for a project in pyGame. The map loads fine when I don't add objects. I use Tiled to create the maps. When I do, I get an attributeError.

I have tried to reinstall pytmx and tried with other maps but nothing seems to work.

```
def gameStart():
    game = True

    tm = pytmx.load_pygame('resources/maps/map1/map.tmx')
    size = tm.width * tm.tilewidth, tm.height * tm.tileheight

    tmx_data = tm

    tw = tmx_data.tilewidth
    th = tmx_data.tileheight
    gt = tmx_data.getTileImageByGid

    while game:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        if tmx_data.background_color:
            screen.fill(tmx_data.background_color)

        for layer in tmx_data.visibleLayers:
            if isinstance(layer, pytmx.TiledLayer):
                for x, y, gid in layer:
                    tile = gt(gid)
                    if tile:
                        screen.blit(tile, (x * tw, y * th))

            elif isinstance(layer, pytmx.TiledObjectGroup):
                pass

            elif isinstance(layer, pytmx.TiledImageLayer):
                image = gt(layer.gid)
                if image:
                    screen.blit(image, (0, 0))



        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(framerate)
```

Which returns the following:

```
File "main.py", line 45, in gameStart
    gt = tmx_data.getTileImageByGid
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytmx/pytmx.py", line 214, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError
AttributeError
```

Comment: where did you get information about `getTileImageByGid` ? Did you check [documentation](https://pytmx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ? It seems it may have  different name - similar to other method `get_tile_properties_by_gid`.

Answer (score 1):

Read [documentation](https://pytmx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) it has different name: 
[get_tile_image_by_gid(gid)](https://pytmx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pytmx.html#pytmx.pytmx.TiledMap.get_tile_image_by_gid)

---

Next time you can check `print( dir(tmx_data) )` to see all methods and properties in `tmx_data`